# How to test a class with google test?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm just learning google test, I have a `class` and I want to test its member function, below is the demo code:

```
class B {
    //......
};
class A {
public:
    //.....
    void add (string s, B* ptrb) { m.insert(s, ptrb); }
    void remove(string s) { 
        auto it = m.find(s);
        if (it != m.end())
            m.erase(it); 
    }
    B* operator[](string s)
    {
        auto it = m.find(s);
        if (it != m.end())
            return (*it).second;
    }
    //.....
protected:
    map<B*> m;
    //.....
}
```

if I want to test  `add` like this:

```
class mygtest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    //....setup
    //....teardown
    A a;
};

TEST_F(mygtest, testadd)
{
    B b1;
    B b2;
    a.add("1", &b1);
    a.add("2", &b2);
    //...how should i do next?
    EXPECT_EQ(.....) //compare with who?
}
```

this is the first question.

the second question is:

In some conditions , I have to call another member function to get a value first , and use `EXPECT_EQ` to test the current member function, **how to test a function without using other member funtion?**  if it's necessary ？

Comment: Aside: Don't fear the `->` operator for pointers or iterators. I feel `it->second` is more readable than `(*it).second`, and it's easier to type as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to just verify that state of `A` has changed as desired.
So just check if it contains added objects.

```cpp
TEST_F(mygtest, testadd)
{
    B b1;
    B b2;
    a.add("1", &b1);
    a.add("2", &b2);

    EXPECT_EQ(a["1"], &b1);
    EXPECT_EQ(a["2"], &b2);
    EXPECT_EQ(a["3"], nullptr);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ezrjdY6hh

Since there is not enough context it is impossible o improve this test (it doesn't look nice).

You can't avoid use of different functions. You are testing behavior of a class. So you are verify that other function do something else after state has been changed.

Do not event think to friend a test with production class. This is bad practice, since this will entangle test with implementation details. You will no be able refactor production code when test check implementation detail.

Here is small refactoring of test I usually do to improve how easy test is maintained: https://godbolt.org/z/Tc1n9Evzs

Comment: And your test (if compiler flag didn't already) might spot issue with OP's code for element not present :-)

Comment: I've fixed that in godbolt, since compiler was complaining about many issues (not only this one).